# Backwards iOS compatibility - Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, realm, ios9

I am trying to update some of my third party libraries to work with Swift 2.0 and Xcode7 and I am having some questions about backwards iOS compatibility.
For instance, I have updated to Locksmith 2.0.0 that is Swift 2 ready.
However, if I have my Deployment Target set to 8.0, Xcode will not build. The compile-error messages states: 'Module file's minimum deployment target is ios9.0 v9.0'.
I have the same problem with Realm.
It builds fine if I set the deployment target to 9.0, but I want to keep backwards compatability to iOS8. From what I understand Swift 2 is compatible with both iOS7 and iOS8.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the issue is being caused by https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2462. Can you try building Realm from source (instructions are available at https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation-swift-20) and seeing if that helps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the *Build Settings* of your project and checking what the based SDK is in the *Architecture* section.

When I converted an app from work the other day to Swift 2, I had to go in and change the base SDK to, I believe, it was the following:

**iphoneos8.0**

It should, by default, be at **iphoneos** (Latest iOS) or **iphoneos9.0** if you just have iOS9 selected.